TargetGroupBinding registering and auto draining the targets registered in TargetGroup
In my current scenario, LoadBalancer, Listener and TargetGroup were created manually. The TargetGroup is of Type instance and contains 1 healthy EC2 instance.
When creating the TargetGroupBinding inside the EKS cluster, I experience that the AWS LoadBalancer Controller registers the worker nodes from the cluster (as expected), but also drains/deregisters the aforementioned EC2 instance within few minutes.
kubectl get svc
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP   172.20.0.1              443/TCP          30d
test-service       NodePort    172.20.100.69           3000:31449/TCP       1d2h
kubectl describe targetgroupbinding test
...
Spec:
Ip Address Type:  ipv4
Service Ref:
Name:            test-service
Port:            3000
Target Group ARN:  arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:738XXXXXXXXX:targetgroup/targetgroupbinding/7be94ec2a5920c65
Target Type:       instance
...
Node Registers
Node auto deregisters/drains
I Inspected AWS Load Balancer Controller Logs and TargetGroupBinding events but found nothing regarding draining.
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.
